# Allocation and deallocation of an object

Tags: iphone, xcode

I created

```
object *Obj = [[Obj alloc] init];
```

What happened?
 After I release it, the object is deallocated.Then what happens?

If I try to create the object again, what will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After *alloc+init* you can use your object **Obj**.

After *releasing* you cannot use it.

When you will try to create object again, new part of memory will be allocated and you can use it again.